# Custom Modal Script - Safari and IE issues

Tags: javascript, css

Safari Issue:
I wrote this simple modal script and for some reason is not working at all in safari browsers osx or ios, nothing. Looks like script wasn't loaded at all, no errors in the console what so ever. I have no idea where to start to solve that problem. Interesting enough I have version in jQuery with the same logic and wont work either.

IE 11:
All seems to be working but for some reason entry animation is omitted. Again no errors in the console have no idea how to start debugging.

I would really appreciate if someone more experienced could check it and point me in the right direction.

Complete code HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Here is complete:
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wikino/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Tried to run script in strict mode and found few badly declared variables, but that does not solve any of the issues. Code updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found all the problems.

First off all I run script in strict mode and I was able to find all issues with incorrectly defined variables.

```
(function(){
   "use strict";
   // Main code here

})();
```

For example defining variable without a key word var will throw an error. I had to make sure all the variables are instantiated correctly. For example:

```
var modalBg;
```

Script was working all the time main issue was related to css and the way I was trying to display elements. I was using:

```
display: flex;
```

Without prefixes obviously it wont work. I dropped the idea of using flexbox and used:

```
display: block;
```

instead.

The reason why animation was breaking in Internet explorer was related to JavaScript itself.

```
modalBg.classList.add('openned', 'animated', 'fadeIn');
```

classList method works fine while adding multiple classes at once in modern browsers: Chrome, Firefox. I found that IE 11 and Safari 5.1.7 have difficulties interpreting code this way so I changed to:

```
modalBg.classList.add('openned');
modalBg.classList.add('animated');
modalBg.classList.add('fadeIn');
```

Adding classes one at the time did the trick and script is executing correctly now.

I updated code on JSBin if anyone is interested :) [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wikino/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11546350)

Comment: @sebastianbrosch my apology. I was Thinking nobody is interested in my subject. I will provide full clarification.